# capture nimbuzz traffic

Tags: xmpp, network-traffic, packet-capture

I need to capture all the traffic, specially during login, between nimbuzz pc client and nimbuzz server. The reason is that i need to debug outgoing packets at login that mark the user visibility status in order to reproduce them in a in-house XMPP client application

I've tried doing this with wireshark, but i seem to be pretty helpless with this tool. Also, the packets i've been able to see are all before the SASL negotiation happens, after that, i cannot see the xml packets being exchanged

any help for how to achieve this task is greatly appreciated (preferably on Windows, since there is no nimbuzz client for linux, in any case i can install one in a VM and monitor the traffic between the VM instance in the linux host)

**Edit** i've added a follow up question [here](https://serverfault.com/q/379331/75759).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a UI perspective, I believe you might want to give [Microsoft's Network Monitor](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=4865) a try. However, packet capture utilities are by nature complex beasties, so there's no getting around the fact that you'll need to become proficient with one. Especially if you're making software based on replicating what you see and understand from network traffic.

NetMon can arrange traffic based on the process that is generating it (as I'm sure Wireshark can, as well). You might have an easier time with NetMon though. I suggest reading "[How to capture network traffic with Network Monitor](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/148942)" to start with. Then "[Analyzing Network Data with Network Monitor.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc723623.aspx)" Finally, "[Network Monitoring with Network Monitor 3.4](http://www.windowsecurity.com/articles/Network-Monitoring-Network-Monitor-34-Part1.html)" is an up to date series that should round out your beginner's education in the matter.

Comment: thanks Wesley for the suggestion, i'm liking the NetMon ui a lot better than WS, i've added a followup question at http://serverfault.com/q/379331/75759. Please have a look if you have time. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can capture all traffic either on your server or on your client and then filter them based on the appropriate ports.

For a discussion about XMPP ports, you can see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452161/which-ports-does-xmpp-uses).